# Why can't I mount my optical drive in Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: linux-mint, mount, fstab, dvd, blu-ray

I'm having trouble mounting my optical drive in Linux Mint 19.3. I figured this constituted a new question because of how outdated other posts have been on the topic.

My system:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux chris-anthemum 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Attempting to mount device to /cdrom:

```
~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /cdrom
mount: /cdrom: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
```

After creating a directory /mnt/dvd and attempting to mount to that:

```
~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/dvd
mount: /mnt/dvd: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
```

**Note** - Even though no medium is found on /dev/sr0, I can eject on the drive and it opens up my optical drive:

```
~$ eject /dev/sr0
```

lsblk shows sr0 as type rom:

```
~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 142.4M  1 loop /snap/opera/73
loop1    7:1    0  93.8M  1 loop /snap/core/8935
loop2    7:2    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop3    7:3    0  28.9M  1 loop /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/15
loop4    7:4    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop5    7:5    0 451.2M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-professional/192
loop6    7:6    0  48.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
loop7    7:7    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1754
loop8    7:8    0 142.4M  1 loop /snap/opera/74
loop9    7:9    0  93.9M  1 loop /snap/core/9066
loop10   7:10   0 445.1M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-professional/196
loop11   7:11   0 160.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   326G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 605.6G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

blkid does not show an entry for my optical drive:

```
~$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="f2c86904-6312-4656-acd1-afa304e9f867" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a0cf3af1-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="1746ce12-039c-4d19-a601-9889026f260a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a0cf3af1-05"
```

lshw shows no disk when a disk is inserted:

```
~$ sudo lshw
*-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRWBD BC-5540H
             vendor: Optiarc
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 201A
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

cdrskin finds the drive:

```
~$ cdrskin --devices
cdrskin 1.4.8 : limited cdrecord compatibility wrapper for libburn
cdrskin: scanning for devices ...
cdrskin: ... scanning for devices done
cdrskin: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  dev='/dev/sr0'  rwrw-- :  'Optiarc '  'DVDRWBD BC-5540H'
```

My fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f2c86904-6312-4656-acd1-afa304e9f867 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=1746ce12-039c-4d19-a601-9889026f260a /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I have also already installed libdvd-pkg, vlc player, ubuntu-restricted-extras, libdvdcss2, libdvdnav4, and libdvdread4. There are no prompts upon insertion of any type of media disk (bluray, dvd, or cd) I feel I'm running in circles and am unsure where to go next.

Comment: I get that message when the is no CD/DVD in the drive.

Comment: @Christian_Cruz you promised to send the output from `cdrecord -media-info -v` ... I meanwhile added sample output to my answer

Answer (score 0):

The message `no medium found` indicates that your drive is curently empty.

If you believe otherwise, this could be a result of:

- an empty medium in the drive
- a defective medium in the drive
- a worn out laser
- a dusty lens in the drive

BTW: here is what you get from a `cdrecord -media-info -v`. Note that I have more then CD drive in the system and need top specify a device parameter that is usially not needed:

```
 cdrecord dev=0,1,0 -media-info -v
Cdrecord-ProDVD-ProBD-Clone 3.02a10 2020/05/05 (i386-pc-solaris2.11 Copyright (C) 1995-2019 Joerg Schilling
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
scsidev: '0,1,0'
scsibus: 0 target: 1 lun: 0
Warning: Using USCSI interface.
Using libscg version 'schily-0.9'.
SCSI buffer size: 64512
atapi: 1
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 0
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identifikation : 'DVD+-RW GSA-H53N'
Revision       : 'B104'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW/DVD-RAM.
Current: CD-R
Profile: DVD-RAM 
Profile: DVD+R/DL 
Profile: DVD+R 
Profile: DVD+RW 
Profile: DVD-R/DL sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-RW sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-RW restricted overwrite 
Profile: DVD-R sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-ROM 
Profile: CD-RW 
Profile: CD-R (current)
Profile: CD-ROM 
Profile: Removable Disk 
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Drive buf size : 1114112 = 1088 KB
Drive pbuf size: 16777215 = 16383 KB
Current Secsize: 2048

    Capacity  Blklen/Sparesz.  Format-type  Type
      334775             2048         0x00  Formatted Media
Mounted media class:      CD
Mounted media type:       CD-R
Disk Is not erasable
data type:                standard
disk status:              complete
session status:           complete
BG format status:         none
first track:              1
number of sessions:       1
first track in last sess: 1
last track in last sess:  1
Disk Is not unrestricted
Disk type: CD-DA or CD-ROM
last start of lead in: 716730
last start of lead out: 1166730

Track  Sess Type   Start Addr End Addr   Size
==============================================
    1     1 Data   0          334774     334775         -1

Last session start address:         0
Last session leadout start address: 334775
```

And this is what you get with an empty drive:

```
 cdrecord dev=0,1,0 -media-info -v
Cdrecord-ProDVD-ProBD-Clone 3.02a10 2020/05/05 (i386-pc-solaris2.11) Copyright (C) 1995-2019 Joerg Schilling
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
scsidev: '0,1,0'
scsibus: 0 target: 1 lun: 0
Warning: Using USCSI interface.
Using libscg version 'schily-0.9'.
SCSI buffer size: 64512
atapi: 1
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 0
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identifikation : 'DVD+-RW GSA-H53N'
Revision       : 'B104'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW/DVD-RAM.
Current: none
Profile: DVD-RAM 
Profile: DVD+R/DL 
Profile: DVD+R 
Profile: DVD+RW 
Profile: DVD-R/DL sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-RW sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-RW restricted overwrite 
Profile: DVD-R sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-ROM 
Profile: CD-RW 
Profile: CD-R 
Profile: CD-ROM 
Profile: Removable Disk 
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Drive pbuf size: 16777215 = 16383 KB
cdrecord: Warning: DMA resid 0 for 'read buffer', actual data is too short.
cdrecord: Warning: The DMA speed test has been skipped.
cdrecord: E/A-Fehler. test unit ready: scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 02 00 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 00 3A 00 00 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x2 Not Ready, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x3A Qual 0x00 (medium not present) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 0.000s timeout 40s
cdrecord: No disk / Wrong disk!
```

If there are other problems than a missing medium, you will get different error messages from the drive.

Comment: Is there any way to test my drive to make sure it's operational? I just edited my question to include the fact that I can perform "eject /dev/sr0" on it and my drives pops open.

Comment: Did you try to run `cdrecord -media-info -v`?

Comment: When I run that command as you typed it, it returns: wodim: Bad Option: -media-info.
Usage: wodim [options] track1...trackn

Use wodim -help
to get a list of valid options.

Use wodim blank=help
to get a list of valid blanking options.

Use wodim dev=b,t,l driveropts=help -checkdrive
to get a list of drive specific options.

Use wodim dev=help
to get a list of possible SCSI transport specifiers.

Comment: Well, I recommended you to run `cdrecord` and not the broken and dead `wodim`...so get the real cdrecord from schilytools and retry. BTW: The`-media-info` option exists since 14 years.

Comment: When I run "cdrecord --help", it returns: Command 'cdrecord' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install wodim
...

Comment: I downloaded and installed that schilytools thing and ran your command... having the same problem. '~$ cdrecord -media-info' --> wodim: Bad Option: -media-info.

Comment: You did choose a Linux distro that did not update cdrecord since 16 years. It is obvoius that you need to compile it yourself when you need a 14 year old feature. There is of course the option to choose an OSS friendly Linux distro that delivers up to date software. BTW: please read your last message, since it shows that you still did not call cdrecord but wodim. So just call cdrecord instead of wodim. Cdrecord by default is installed at /opt/schily/bin and it is a good idea to deinstall wodim and other related unmailtained variants.

Comment: Let me ask this question... what information are you looking for? I'll append my question to add more information.

Comment: Well, you asked for further help and to get more specific information on the problem you have, This is why I asked you to send the output from `cdrecord -media-info -v` as this asks the drive for more information about the current medium. You claim that you now have cdrecord, please run it and send the results. If you don't, I cannot give further help.

Comment: Just let me know how to completely delete cdrecord. It is not performing correctly for me. I downloaded it from a tar.gz ball. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Cdrecord works correctly, you just need to call it instead of this defective wodim. So start with completely deleting wodim.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the PC/Laptop with a CD *in the drive*. My Mint does the same thing, it wont even see a CD drive if it cant "see it" inserted during boot.